# Automatically replace "$" by "\(" in latex-mode

Tags: auctex, electric-pair-mode

In latex mode, using `\( ... \)` is preferred over `$ ... $`, so in my configuration I have the following

```
(sp-local-pair modes "$" nil :actions :rem)
(sp-local-pair modes "\\(" "\\)" :trigger "$")
```

This way, when I try to insert `$` the pair `\( \)` are inserted instead. This works well, however, for some reason if I select some text and press `$` the pair `\( \)` are inserted after the text instead of wrapping the text with them.

If I press `\(` instead the selected text is wrapped correctly.

Is there a way to fix this so that if I press `$` with a selected text, the text is wrapped with `\( ... \)`?

Comment: Does it work if you add `:trigger-wrap "$"` after `:trigger "$"`?

Comment: No, that did not work.

Comment: I see the issue now with emacs -Q. In addition to adding `:trigger-wrap "$"` I also had to require `smartparens-latex`. If that works for you we'll have to dig there to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @jagrg suggestion (to add `:trigger-wrap "$"`) I found everything works as expected if I *don't* remove the `$` pair from my modes

I.e., I had to comment out this line

```
(sp-local-pair 'latex-mode "$" nil :actions :rem)
```

This line alone does the trick

```
(sp-local-pair 'latex-mode "\\(" "\\)" :trigger "$" :trigger-wrap "$")
```